# How to create this text effect with css3?

Tags: html, css, border, effect

[Help me please, how to create this effect with css3][1]
I've tried many create tools to make this effect but it's don't work

you can view my picture in this link, I'm noob, I don't know how to attach picture here : https://ibb.co/kn1aKa

here is codes in CSS file

```css
@font-face { font-family: 'UTM Cookies'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('UTM Cookies'), local('UTM Cookies'), url(../fonts/UTM-Cookies_0.woff) format('woff');

}

.headline-wrap h1 { font-size: 20px; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; color: #000; font-family: UTM Cookies; padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px; color: #FF972F; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="headline-wrap">
  <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code so far.

Comment: I wrote in css:

@font-face {

 font-family: 'UTM Cookies';

 font-style: normal;

 font-weight: 400;
 
 src: local('UTM Cookies'), local('UTM Cookies'), url(../fonts/UTM-Cookies_0.woff) format('woff');

}


and the class :
.headline-wrap h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: UTM Cookies;
    padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;
    color: #FF972F;
    text-align: center;

}

Comment: You can use Stack Overflow snippets to add a short snippet of code that is relevant to your question.

Comment: thanks Chava G, I did it

Comment: First result on google for add text glow css: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the CSS3 [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow) property, and you would need to apply it several times to get it all around the text.

The text shadow property takes values for the x-offset, y-offset, blur-radius, and color.

```
          /* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | color */
text-shadow: 1px        1px        2px           white;
```

It does not take a value for the spread, but you can apply multiple shadows with different offsets as a comma-separated list to achieve the desired effect.

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px white, -2px -2px white, 2px -2px white, -2px 2px white;
```

```css
@font-face { font-family: 'UTM Cookies'; font-style: normal; font-weight: 400; src: local('UTM Cookies'), local('UTM Cookies'), url(../fonts/UTM-Cookies_0.woff) format('woff');
}

.headline-wrap {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.headline-wrap h1 { font-size: 20px; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px; color: #000; font-family: UTM Cookies; padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px; color: #FF972F; text-align: center; 
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px white, -2px -2px white, 2px -2px white, -2px 2px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="headline-wrap">
  <h1>Some text</h1>
</div>
```